# Add variable to RegEx

Tags: regex, apache-flex

For example, I've got var for RegEx `DSX-?2` 
I need add this var to RegEx and get this `.match(/DSX-?2/gi)`

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `RegExp` object by using the `new RegExp()` constructor or by assigning a RegExp literal to a variable:

```
var pattern1:RegExp = /DSX-?2/gi;
// or
var pattern2:RegExp = new RegExp("DSX-?2", "gi");
```

Answer (score 0):

var reg:RegExp = new RegExp("DSX-?2", "gi");